# How can I receive an access token for SkyDrive Pro REST calls, from a remote application (no SharePoint app)

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, oauth

I am trying to do the following:

create a web application that does `REST` calls with JavaScript to a Office365 account on SharePoint to list folders / files on SkyDrive Pro. I know how to construct the REST calls themselves, but I don't know where I can request an OAuth `access_token`.

*Please note: SkyDrive Pro, not Skydrive (I know how to do that one)*

To summup, how do I construct the url to go to the STS of SharePoint and ask for an `access_token`.

I have already registered for a `CLIENT_ID` in the app catalog.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blog that I wrote before few months explaining the entire [Auth process using plain HTTP Requests in ASP.net](http://jomit.blogspot.com/2013/03/authentication-and-authorization-with.html). This should give you a pretty good idea of all the Url's and steps that you need to perform in JavaScript to get the token. Once you have the token you can access Skydrive pro like a normal document library using simple list REST API's. The TemplateId for skydrive pro library is 700.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for! However, now another question: do I have to supply a Redirect Uri? I was hoping that it would redirect to the caller when none is supplied. Otherwise I have to put my server in Https mode...

Comment: I haven't tried without redirect uri but I think it's a mandatory field.